# sklearn adjusted mutual information score breaks on large set

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

```
from sklearn.metrics import adjusted_mutual_info_score
import numpy as np

a = np.random.randint(0,2,30000000)
b = np.random.randint(0,2,30000000)

print(a.shape)
print(b.shape)

c = adjusted_mutual_info_score(a,b)

print(c)
```

If you run the following code, you will get out:

```
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in log
  log_outer = -np.log(outer) + log(pi.sum()) + log(pj.sum())
nan
```

I don't understand why is that, but if you make a smaller sets of 1000 values, everything runs perfectly. Could anyone explain to me what is happening and how to fix this? I would appreciate it.

Comment: Works for me and returns a value. I only get a warning "sklearn\metrics\cluster\supervised.py:732: FutureWarning: The behavior of AMI will change in version 0.22.".

Comment: @Trilarion Thanks, may i ask what version of sklearn you have?

Comment: 0.20.3 installed via conda.

Comment: @Trilarion Thanks